# Is it possible to print a preprocessor variable in C?

Tags: c, variables, c-preprocessor

Is is possible to print to stderr the value of a preprocessor variable in **C**?  For example, what I have right now is:

```
#define PP_VAR (10)
#if (PP_VAR > 10)
    #warning PP_VAR is greater than 10
#endif
```

But what I'd like to do is:

```
#define PP_VAR (10)
#if (PP_VAR > 10)
    #warning PP_VAR=%PP_VAR%
#endif
```

Is something like this possible in **C**?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can print out the value of a preprocessor variable under visual studio. The following prints out the value of _MSC_VER:

```
#define STRING2(x) #x
#define STRING(x) STRING2(x)

#pragma message(STRING(_MSC_VER))
```

Not sure how standard this is though.

Comment: Its not standard, but GCC, MSVC, CLANG... (probably others support it too)

Comment: VisualStudio apparently not

Comment: @derHugo: sorry but I have just tested using Visual Studio 2017 and C++17 and this work without problem.I have tested with a custom preprocessor variable, not _MSC_VER !

Answer (score 23):

This works with GCC 4.4.3:

```
#define STRING2(x) #x
#define STRING(x) STRING2(x)
#pragma message "LIBMEMCACHED_VERSION_HEX = " STRING(LIBMEMCACHED_VERSION_HEX)
```

yields:

```
src/_pylibmcmodule.c:1843: note: #pragma message: LIBMEMCACHED_VERSION_HEX = 0x01000017
```

Answer (score 6):

Many C compilers support `#warning`, but it is not defined by the C standard unless you're using C23 or later.

However, GCC at least does not do pre-processing on the data that follows, which means it is hard to see the value of a variable.

```
#define PP_VAR 123
#warning "Value of PP_VAR = " PP_VAR
#warning "Value of PP_VAR = " #PP_VAR
#warning "Value of PP_VAR = " ##PP_VAR
```

GCC produces:

```
x.c:2:2: warning: #warning "Value of PP_VAR = " PP_VAR
x.c:3:2: warning: #warning "Value of PP_VAR = " #PP_VAR
x.c:4:2: warning: #warning "Value of PP_VAR = " ##PP_VAR
```

---

The C23 standard is expected to say:

> #### §6.10.6 Diagnostic directives
>
> **Semantics**
>
> A preprocessing directive of either form
>
> ```
> # error pp-tokensopt new-line
> # warning pp-tokensopt new-line
> ```
>
> causes the implementation to produce a diagnostic message that includes the specified sequence of
> preprocessing tokens.

Since it specifies that the diagnostic message includes the preprocessing tokens, macros will not be expanded in the message for either `#error` or `#warning`.  None of the standards that specify `#error` explicitly specify that the compilation of the translation unit should fail if the directive is executed — only that a diagnostic shall be produced.  Nevertheless, there is a reasonable expectation that if a `#error` directive is executed, the TU should fail to compile.  By contrast, executing a `#warning` directive should not cause the compilation of the TU to fail.

Comment: So when you say "it is hard to see the value of a variable," what you really mean is you CAN'T see it.

Comment: Roughly - yes; I have not worked out a way to see it, which is not the same as "there is no way to see it".

Comment: I ***think*** this is what I am trying to do.... I want to know what the runtime library is defining `SSIZE_MAX` to as a string (like `0`, `INT_MAX` or `LONG_MAX`), but the stringy is only returning `SSIZE_MAX` (the left hand side of the define).

Answer (score 3):

Use the preprocessor token-pasting operator: ##TOKEN_NAME

As previously noted, the preprocessor directives you are using are non-standard, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you are doing is actually non-standard. Firstly, the `#warning` or `#warn` directive is not standard. Secondly, when using the preprocessor, the line must begin with the pound symbol, without any spaces:

```
#ifdef BLAH1
#    define BLAH2 // OK, because pound is at the very left.
#endif

#ifdef BLAH3
     #define BLAH4 // Works on many compilers, but is non-standard.
#endif
```

Since you are already using a non-standard extension, you will need to look up the documentation of the particular preprocessor/compiler that you are using to see what it says about `#warning`.

Comment: Your second point is not correct - C89 lifted that restriction.  The # must be the first symbol on the line, but it may be preceded by white space (but not by comments).

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I'm still living in the dark ages. Can you point me to the relevant document for that?

Comment: Wow. I came later to the game than I thought - I never knew about that restriction at all.

Comment: @Jonathan: There is completely no issue with preceding any preprocessing directive with comment (at least c comment /*..*/) it will be replaced with single space in translation phase #3. Preprocessing directives are handled in phase #4 hence are not impacted by preceding c comment.

Comment: @Artur: You're right — but in the bad old days (really old days, pre-C89 standard days), comments were not allowed.  My mix-up.  (Mind you, there'd have to be a very, very good reason to include a comment before a preprocessor directive, and I can't think of any.)

Comment: @Jonathan: Sure - I do not see a reason to put a comment before preprocessing directive so what I wrote is just about doability and not any good/bad coding practise.