# Kernel compilation fails due to PF_MAX > 44

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I have a QEMU VM running an image of the Linux kernel 4.14.78.

On the host machine (a server with 96 cores), I am trying to compile a new update for the kernel with some changes I have made.
To make this process faster, I was using the host machine to compile for the target VM.

To do that I follow these steps:

- copy the `/boot/config-4.14.78` file from VM to host
- put the copied file into the kernel source-code root directory, renaming it to `.config` in my
- run `make clean` to clean it
- run `make menuconfig` just to update the configs
- run `make -j$(nproc)`

However, I am getting this error:

```sh
  AS      arch/x86/purgatory/setup-x86_64.o
  CC      arch/x86/purgatory/sha256.o
  AS      arch/x86/purgatory/entry64.o
  CC      arch/x86/purgatory/string.o
In file included from scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:49:
./security/selinux/include/classmap.h:245:2: error: #error New address family defined, please update secclass_map.
  245 | #error New address family defined, please update secclass_map.
      |  ^~~~~
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:102: scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:587: scripts/selinux/mdp] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders.c:19:
./security/selinux/include/classmap.h:245:2: error: #error New address family defined, please update secclass_map.
  245 | #error New address family defined, please update secclass_map.
      |  ^~~~~
  CHK     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:102: scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:587: scripts/selinux/genheaders] Error 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:587: scripts/selinux] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I have checked what causes this, and turns out that it is because of the:

```sh
include/linux/socket.h:211:#define AF_MAX       44  /* For now.. */
include/linux/socket.h:260:#define PF_MAX       AF_MAX
```

Then, I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204202/is-it-possible-to-print-a-preprocessor-variable-in-c) to print out the definition of `PF_MAX` at preprocessing time, and turns out that the `PF_MAX` is `45`:

```sh
In file included from scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:49:
./security/selinux/include/classmap.h:247:9: note: #pragma message: 45
  247 | #pragma message(STRING(PF_MAX))
      |         ^~~~~~~
./security/selinux/include/classmap.h:250:2: error: #error New address family defined, please update secclass_map.
  250 | #error New address family defined, please update secclass_map.
      |  ^~~~~
```

This `45` makes no sense for me, because I just checked that it is supposed to be `44`.

I wonder if the build is considering the host machine instead of the target?

**P.S.:** These steps works fine on my local machine, which is a 8-cores machine, look the kernel version:

```sh
uname -a
Linux campes-note 5.4.86 #1 SMP Fri Jan 1 16:26:25 -03 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I tried to compile the kernel without any of my changes, following th above steps mentioned, and it did not compile as well, I get the same error.

**UPDATE 2:**
I found out that somehow, the compilation is looking at the host `/usr/src/linux-headers-x.x.x` files.
Instead, it should point to the same version as the target.

For that, I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270123/how-to-create-usr-src-linux-headers-version-files) but I did not success. I am having a problem in one of the steps stated on this tutorial.

Comment: Does it build without your magic changes in the code?

Comment: I just tried to compile here with the clean kernel source code and I got the same error. Actually, this error has nothing to do with my changes.  My changes themselves are minor on the JBD2 Journaling Layer, I just added some `printk` to see what is going on.

Comment: Yes, I did it already. I started from: `wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.14.78.tar.xz` to download the version I am trying to compile. From a clean build I get the same problem. I thought it would be the kernel headers or something, by folowing [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270123/how-to-create-usr-src-linux-headers-version-files) and I could not follow the steps due to some other error non-related to this one.

Comment: Great, I am so focused on `4.14.78` because this was the version I was studying. Hopefully, with a `diff` the `4.14.78` may not differ that much from `4.14.214` at the JBD2 layer.

Comment: Then, that patch you mentioned can solve it to .78, I gonna try now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Gathered from the now removed comments)

I have tried myself to build myself v4.14.78 followed by the latest available v4.14.214. I have found that former fails while the latter builds. So, I have bisected down to v4.14.116 that first builds correctly. Then I simple looked into the changes and found commit [760f8522ce08](https://git.kernel.org/stable/c/760f8522ce08) ("selinux: use kernel linux/socket.h for genheaders and mdp") in the Linux stable tree which fixes the issue.

You may try to cherry-pick it to your branch and compile again.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to go straight to the `linux-4.14.214` as you mentioned. It is compiling and my QEMU VM is running this new kernel:
`qemu@fvm:~$ uname -a
Linux fvm 4.14.214 #3 SMP Tue Jan 12 20:18:24 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`